# Missing opencv library while building a shared python library form .cpp file

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost

I have a c++ file and I want to build a shared library(.so file)from that. Here is the .cpp file:

```
#include "extract_features.hpp"

boost::python::object hog_feature_extract(boost::python::object &gray,    boost::python::object &pts2d, boost::python::object &pts3d) {
static Mat m_gray, m_pts2d, m_pts3d, m_feature_vector;

// Convert into opencv land...
pyopencv_to(gray.ptr(), m_gray, "info", true);
pyopencv_to(pts2d.ptr(), m_pts2d, "info", true);
pyopencv_to(pts3d.ptr(), m_pts3d, "info", true);

// Function call
hog_feature_extractor::shared_extractor().extract(m_gray, m_pts2d, m_pts3d, m_feature_vector);

// Output
PyObject *p_feature_vector = pyopencv_from(m_feature_vector);
boost::python::object boostPyObjFrame(boost::python::handle<>((PyObject*)p_feature_vector));

return boostPyObjFrame;
}
```

And here is the .hpp file:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "python_helper.hpp"
#include "hog_feature_extractor.hpp"
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

boost::python::object hog_feature_extract(boost::python::object &gray,    boost::python::object &pts2d, boost::python::object &pts3d);
void *extract_pyarray(PyObject *x) {
    return PyObject_TypeCheck(x, &PyArray_Type) ? x : 0;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(extract_features) {
import_array();
boost::python::converter::registry::insert( &extract_pyarray, type_id<PyArrayObject>( ) );
def("hog_feature_extract", &hog_feature_extract);
def("hog_feature_preprocess", &hog_feature_preprocess);
def("sift_feature_extract", &sift_feature_extract);
}

#pragma GCC visibility pop
#endif
```

And here is the command I used to build the shared library:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -lstdc++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-z,defs -o /projects/glass_development/lib/linux/extract_features.so  extract_features/extract_features.cpp processing/sift_feature_extractor.cpp processing/hog_feature_extractor.cpp processing/pre_extraction_helper.cpp helpers/python_helper.cpp processing/base_feature_extractor.cpp -lpython2.6 -lboost_python -I/share/sw/free/boost/1.41.0/include/ -I/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/include/ -I/projects/glass_development/src/native/processing/ -I/projects/glass_development/src/native/helpers/ -I/usr/include/python2.6
```

I tried to add all the necessarily paths for other .cpp files and libraries including opencv and boost libraries. But it gives me some errors that seems it can not load opencv libraries, here is the part of error log:

```
/tmp/ccVzk9cx.o: In function `pyopencv_to(_object const*, cv::Mat&, char const*, bool)':
python_helper.cpp:(.text+0xb54): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(int,  int const*, int, void*, unsigned long const*)'
python_helper.cpp:(.text+0xc04): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
python_helper.cpp:(.text+0xc1a): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
python_helper.cpp:(.text+0xc2d): undefined reference to `cv::transpose(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'
```

if I remove  "-Wl,-z,defs" option in the above command, it buils .so file without any errors, but when I want to import it in a python script, it can not load the library.

What I am missing? any suggestion?

Here is the output of

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

command:

```
-I/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/include/opencv 

-I/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/include

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_contrib.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_core.so

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_features2d.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_flann.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_gpu.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_highgui.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_legacy.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_ml.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_ocl.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_photo.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_stitching.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_superres.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_ts.a 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_video.so 

/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/lib/libopencv_videostab.so 

/usr/lib64/libXext.so /usr/lib64/libX11.so

 /usr/lib64/libICE.so /usr/lib64/libSM.so 

/usr/lib64/libGL.so /usr/lib64/libGLU.so 

-lcufft -lcublas -lnpps -lnppi -lnppc -lcudart -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Comment: I guess you are not linking against libopencv. Try adding ```-lopencv``` to your command line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added that library as well and now it gives me this error: ` cannot find -lopencv`. I also added the path for the opencv library, but still giving the same error.

Comment: What does ```pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv``` print? Can you add the options that this command prints to your command line?

Comment: It gives me lots of options, I tried most of them and still am getting the same error.

Comment: can you post the output of ```pkg-config --libs opencv``` at least? You are clearly not linking to the opencv library.

Comment: Should I add them with `-I` option or `-L` option? and does the order matter?

Comment: Order matters. I think you need at least an ```-l``` option (lowercase L).

Comment: if you run your compilation like this: ```g++ [...] $(pkg-config --libs opencv) ```  does it compile? (replace ... with all your options that you used previously)

Comment: It still gives me the same error : `cannot find -lopencv` :(

Comment: don't put ```-lopencv```, only the ```$(pkg-config --libs opencv)```

Comment: I removed the `-lopencv` and got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :-). I added this result as an answer. Please accept the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The command line was missing the linking options for opencv, added via pkg-config: 
`$(pkg-config --libs opencv)`.

When adding this option, the shared library compiles correctly:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -lstdc++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-z,defs -o /projects/glass_development/lib/linux/extract_features.so  extract_features/extract_features.cpp processing/sift_feature_extractor.cpp processing/hog_feature_extractor.cpp processing/pre_extraction_helper.cpp helpers/python_helper.cpp processing/base_feature_extractor.cpp -lpython2.6 -lboost_python -I/share/sw/free/boost/1.41.0/include/ -I/share/sw/free/opencv/2.4.9/include/ -I/projects/glass_development/src/native/processing/ -I/projects/glass_development/src/native/helpers/ -I/usr/include/python2.6 $(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```